# add custom metadata to woocommerce webhook hook

Tags: woocommerce, webhooks, hook-woocommerce

I have a webhook set up to trigger when there is a new order and it works just fine, I use it in a custom app to notify when there is a new order. But now i need to be able to add custom meta data to the webhook, is this possible?

the current output

```
   {
 "id": 1,
 "name": "alert new order",
"status": "active",
 "topic": "order.created",
 "resource": "order",
 "event": "created",
 "hooks": [
"woocommerce_new_order"
  ],
```

is there a way to add meta data in this hooks array or in the same json like

```
    {
 "id": 1,
 "name": "alert new order",
"status": "active",
 "topic": "order.created",
 "resource": "order",
 "event": "created",
 "metdadata": "mata data value"
 "hooks": [
"woocommerce_new_order"
  ],
```

The php (found it searching around)so far i had tried but simple does not work or do anything

```
     add_action( 'woocommerce_webhook_payload', 'sendsikkert_woocommerce_webhook_payload' );

    function sendsikkert_woocommerce_webhook_payload( $payload, $resource, $resource_id, $id ) {

    $order  = wc_get_order( $resource_id );

   $ssmail = get_post_meta( $order->get_order_number(), '_token', true );
   $cvrnr  = get_post_meta( $order->get_order_number(), 'restaurante', true );

    $payload['order']['Sendsikkert_email'] = $ssmail;
    $payload['order']['CVRNR']             = $cvrnr;

   return $payload;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm working off the same example with the same results and searching in circles for the right answer.

Comment: unfortunately no